# Adjusting Max File Size - Stuck at 16M After Adjusting general.php

Tags: upload, limit

I'm adjusting the maxUploadFileSize in Craft, to 50MB.
In following the post below, I made several adjustments to both: php.ini and craft/config/general.php.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php

First, I adjusted settings in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize 
post_max_size
```

In general.php (craft/config), the following was already set:

```
  define('URI_SCHEME',  ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) ? "https://" : "http://" );
  define('SITE_URL',    URI_SCHEME . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/');
  define('BASEPATH',       realpath(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/../') . '/');

 return array(

  '*' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'siteUrl'  => SITE_URL,
        'basePath' => BASEPATH,
        'maxUploadFileSize' => 62914560,
        ),
  ),
  'dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
  )


 );
```

I know that that is around 62MB, but I keep receiving an error message saying that there is a 16MB limit on files.  All other files great than 2MB and less than 16MB now are upload-able.
Can anyone make a suggestion as to why the standard CraftCMS default of 16MB is now in place?

Thanks for any leads

Comment: Basic question, but worth a double check. Is your `maxUploadFileSize` setting being applied to your current environment?

Comment: Go into the Utilities section in the Control Panel, click on PHP info and do a Cmd/Ctrl+F for `upload_max_filesize`. Does it say `50M`?

Comment: Also, what web server is this? For Nginx, for example, you'll want to do `client_max_body_size 0;` to set it to "no limit" https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft/blob/master/sites-available/somedomain.com.conf

Comment: Thanks - this is IIS - Windows Server.
Regarding applying maxUploadFileSize to my current environment, is there a command which will reveal which settings are being applied from which (if there are multiple) general.php file?

Comment: Is this Craft 2 or Craft 3?

Comment: This is Craft 2

Comment: IIS has a maxAllowedContentLength setting you can adjust in web.config that you might be running into.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your php `upload_max_filesize` is set to 16M, you'll need to adjust that.

Answer (score 1):

Since Craft 2.1 there is a setting `maxUploadFileSize` in `craft/config/general.php`. You should change this setting as well. Default value is 16777216 (16MB).

https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#maxuploadfilesize